# rsync push - can rsync be made as easy to use as "hg push"

Tags: git, mercurial, rsync, dvcs

Q: is there a way to use rsync or some similar tool so that you can "rsync++ pull" or "rysnc++ push" as easily as you can "git pull" or "hg push" in a DVCS?

So that you can indicate that a directory tree is rsynced, e.g. via an rc file in RTREE_ROOT, to particular remote systems

and then, if you are deep in such a tree, you can just type in "rsync++ push" or "rsync++ push remote-system-name"

and the hypothetical rsync++ tool would crawl up the filesystem tree until it finds RSYNC_ROOT, a directory marked, e.g. with an rc file.

Rather than having to type something like (which changes according to where you are_)

```
rsync -r ../../../Rysnc_Root_Name remote-system:path/to/rsync/place/on/remote
```

Just be able to do

```
rsync++ push remote-name
```

or even

```
rsync++ push
```

when there is a default push target

**Background**:

I often use a distributed version control tool such as git, mercurial (hg), or bazaar (bzr).

I find it far easier to keep DVCS trees in sync than to use rsync: once set up, one just says "git push" or "hg pull", possibly followed by "hg update".

I.e. the DVCS can find the root of the current tree, and can map it to remote trees or repos that need to be updated.

AFAIK, rsync does not do this.

But I can think of rysnc as a zeroth-level DVCS - okay, a distributed replication service. Unfortunately, the command line interface doesn't allow this pleasant fiction to be perceived.

Sometimes I use a DVCS when all I really need is rsync, just to make it easier to type.  But then I have to ensure that the remote user knows to use "hg update" in the remote target directory tree.

---

I think there are some fairly generic aspects to this, that might be useful in multiople tools, not just rsync and DVCS tools like git/hg/bzr:

(1) in a directory tree, find some "root"
e.g. by walking up .., ../.., to look for some special marking like a .hg file, etc.
e.g. by l

(Issue: nesting. E.g. I often have hg repos in bzr repos, or vice versa - which is basically a klugey way of trying to create nested subrepos, which so many DVCS tools do not handle. Might be nice to allow skipping of certain levels, or merging.)

(2) having found such a root, specify pleasant, human friendly, shorthands,
e.g. mapping a name like "remote" to "ssh://host:port//path/to/corresponding"

or using default, or default-for-operation (like default=pull or default-push).

(typically merging stuff in the root with stuff in ~/.toolrc)

The monadic version is to find a root, and possibly, given the root, to find a config file, possibly merging.

The dyadic version observes that often commands involve a directiory tree under such a root, and another directory tree specified in the config file.

A multiadic version might allow you to push to multiple remotes.

We already have DVCS tools that follow this pattern: git/hg/mercurial.

My immediate wish is for an rsync-like rool.

If you think about it, non-distributed version control tools like CVS and SVN, and the umpteen RCS wrappers, solve the "how do I find the remote" with a link dir per xdir in the tree.  (As I pointed out in a paper a long time ago.)

What other tools might benefit from something like this?

?? how about a tool that converted relative symlinks to absolute and vice versa:  e.g. copy a tree, using relative symlinks for everything within the tree, and absolute for everything outside.

Comment: You could configure the remote hg server to do an automatic update [like this](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F)

Comment: @Edward: thanks.  I often configure my DVCS repos to do an automatic update - although I must admit I had forgotten how to do so for hg.  (.hg/hgrc not being DVCS'ed is a pain; I understand the security issues).  But it seems like a bit of overkill to use DVCS when rsync would do.  Moreover, I often find myself rsync'in a tree that contains multiple .hg and .git and .bzr repo/workspaces - and now perforce. Nevertheless, thanks.  // oh, yeah, the other problem: I use branches.  hg update, whether using tip or the default branch, is often not what I want.

Comment: I think there are two fairly generic aspects to this: // (1) in a directory tree, find some "root", e.g. by walking up .., ../.., to look for some special marking.  (Issue: nesting)